# conserving operands of a calculation

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, calculator

So, here is the main idea, I'm trying to make a calculator.

```
private void _1_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        resultBoxText += "1";
        resultBox.Text = resultBoxText;
    }
    private void _2_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        resultBoxText += "2";
        resultBox.Text = resultBoxText;
    }
    private void _3_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        resultBoxText += "3";
        resultBox.Text = resultBoxText;
    }
    private void plus_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        resultBoxText += "+";
        resultBox.Text = resultBoxText;
    }

    private void minus_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        resultBoxText += "-";
        resultBox.Text = resultBoxText;
    }
```

The code above is for the user when he inputs the number or the operand the text in the textbox changes.
Now, how do i make the actual calculations ? in a seperate function (with arguments) ?
is one variable enough for all of the operands or should i make an array ?
How do i add them together, as the input goes ?
ex: I press "2" then "+" then "3", how do i gather them in the result ?
I don't really know how to start :/

Comment: Oh man. You're opening a can of worms here. Tips: Restrict yourself to a very small set of valid inputs to start (a small grammar).

Comment: you mean, i make this code shorter ?

Comment: What I mean is that you should restrict your calculator to a very small subset of operations first. a + b, a - b, a * b, a / b maybe. Afterwards, you can worry about parsing more complicated expressions with parentheses and order of operations concerns.

Comment: Are you saying that you have a string say "2+3" and you want to calculate it?

Comment: That would be cool if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to only add/substract 1,2,3,4 then one variable should be enough. Just make all neccessary calculations right in your event handlers.

Comment: well, i'm not only going for those, these are just the starter.

Answer (score 0):

I recently tried doing this exact same thing. I came up with the following, surprisingly simple solution. First off, add a reference to the COM libarary `MSScriptControl` ([how to add and remove references in VS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)). Then, after all your number button click events:

```
private void _1_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    resultBoxText += "1";
    resultBox.Text = resultBoxText;
}
private void _2_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    resultBoxText += "2";
    resultBox.Text = resultBoxText;
}
private void _3_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    resultBoxText += "3";
    resultBox.Text = resultBoxText;
}
private void plus_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    resultBoxText += "+";
    resultBox.Text = resultBoxText;
}

private void minus_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    resultBoxText += "-";
    resultBox.Text = resultBoxText;
}
```

put some code for your equals button:

```
private void equals_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MSScriptControl.ScriptControl sc = new MSScriptControl.ScriptControl();
    sc.Language = "VBScript";
    //Using try catch statement just in case a user enters an invalid expression. 
    //This becomes more useful when the application gets more advanced. 
    try
    {
        object result = sc.Eval(resultBoxText);
        //Output the result somehow. E.g.: resultBox.Text = result.ToString();
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid expression!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Just this small amount of code, can take a string such as "7*9-6+3/6" and will return the correct answer of "57.5".
One thing I must mention, however, is how this can not properly process a string like "1(1)".
Technically it should view that as "1*1", however it just raises an error. So, I had to do a little bit of coding to get around that. But I'll just let you cross that bridge when you come to it... :)

One thing I might add: If your number buttons all contain the simple text of "1" or "2" or "+", then you can condense your button clicks by a *large* amount.

```
private void num_button_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button b = (Button)sender;
    resultBoxText += b.Text;
    resultBox.Text = resultBoxText;
}
```

Then for **all** your number buttons, refer them to the num_button_click code whenever they are clicked. This would also work for all your operator buttons ("+").

If on the other hand, your buttons contain text like "click for one", then just stick with your original code; ignore me.

And I just realized that all your click events have `RoutedEventArgs`. Are you using WPF? I just assumed it was winforms. Well, anyways, the code should still work... I hope that's what you are looking for.